# What is equivalent to Document.setBoost() from Lucene 3.6 in Lucene 4.1?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to upgrade from Lucene 3.6 to 4.1 and cannot find where document boosts have gone

What is equivalent to Document.setBoost() from Lucene 3.6 in Lucene 4.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at [What is equivalent to Document.setBoost() from Lucene 3.6 in Lucene 4.1](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201302.mbox/%3C009301ce0df4%24c1a52510%2444ef6f30%24@thetaphi.de%3E). Pay special attention to the last message in the thread where the migration guide is quoted.

Comment: Mark, it is the same guy asking the same question in lucene-java@ ;-)

Comment: Yes, interesting that I got an answer from Lucene mailing list, however the reply was confusing as it recommends a different solution to what it says in the migration guide.

Comment: Off-hand, I would go with what is in the migration guide. I have not had any problems so far with the Lucene documentation, so the migration guide seems like a good start to me (IMHO).